# discount proportional to the number of items bought

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm creating a game that offers 10 in-app purchases. I'm wondering, is it possible to add discount to in-app purchases if for example 3 products were bought together? I am currently in the process of acquiring international credit card for developer enrolment and I have no access to iTunes Connect myself. I've read a few articles which stated that non-consumable products are given price in iTunes Connect. So is it possible to create a business model that gives discount proportional to the number of items bought? I realise this is probably not the best place to ask this question. Direct me where to post it and I will delete it. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to assign the discount in-app, but you could always define a separate purchase for each 3 product combo and just assign it the price with the discount included. Admittedly, this sounds like a pain, but I see no other way.

Comment: A lot of pain indeed, specially if I raise the number of offered in-app purchases. How about assigning a price to the actual number of items bought and not a specific combo. There is no need for iTunes Connect to know exactly which combo was bought(I can figure that myself in code), only what number of items were bought. Could this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through iTunes Connect, it appears that you can create a product, and have it be called "3 items" or something, and have the user purchase that.

I'm not sure what type of product it should be though. A non-consumable can only be purchased once, meaning that you can only purchase one bundle of 3 things, which I'm sure you don't want. A consumable seems to be the only other option, but then you can't restore purchases. Even if you did manage to get restoring the purchase working, you would not be able to tell which products were purchased in that 3 item bundle, unless you saved that data on your own server or something.

Comment: Okay, I'm thinking of creating 4 bundles of "3 items" and once purchased I remove selected items from in-app store. so there is no way they exceed number 10. Thank you.